Webpack Module Federation: How does initial consume will work inside ConsumeSharedRuntime module?
I'm working with Webpack's Module Federation and trying to understand how the initial consumption behaves within the ConsumeSharedRuntime module. Specifically, I want to know how shared dependencies are managed or initialized on first load and and how initialConsumes = [] with module id is getting created
Could someone clarify:
How does Webpack handle shared dependencies in the ConsumeSharedRuntime module during initial load?
What are the best practices to ensure we will not get eager consumption error if there is initial consumes array is available.
shared: ['@angular/core': {singleton: true, eager: true}, '@angular/common': {singleton: true, eager: true}, 'rxjs': {singleton: true, eager: true}]
Github link for webpack code
